# access the contents of a private repository through github api

Tags: github-api

according to the documentation I can get the contents of a particular file in a github repo like this:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path
```

which indeed works for my public repos? But what about my private ones? How can I have my applications access their contents?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add [authorization](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/oauth-authorizations) to your request.

One way to do this is through the headers. Add both of the following headers:

```
User-Agent: 'YOUR_USERNAME'
Authorization: 'token YOUR_TOKEN'
```

Comment: Still the same error with `curl -u 'MyUserName` as well as with `curl -H  "User-Agent: USERNAME Authorization: token My_TOKEN"` - and my credentials are double-checked be fine

Comment: Make sure that not only the token is correct but also you set the correct permissions. In your case where you want to access the files of a private repo you need the "repo" permission for your token.